# Can VC++ programs built with platform toolset "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" run on Windows Server 2003/2008?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

Can programs build in VS2012 with platform toolset "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" run on Windows Server 2003/2008?

I'm keen to take advantage of all the new C++11 goodness but need to target machines running VS2008.

If it won't run by default what configuration changes should I make to be able to target this platform and still benefit from all the compiler's new features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this a test and can answer that **yes** they will run provided that the VC++11 re-distributable DLLs are available on the path i.e. *msvcp110.dll*, *msvcr110.dll* etc..

Comment: You can find the redistributable package at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score 0):

To run VS2012 compiled C++ apps on Windows Server 2003, you should use a "v110_xp" platform toolset which is included in Visuasl Studio 2012 Update 1. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx):

> The Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp) platform toolset that's included in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 is a version of the Windows 7 SDK that was included in Visual Studio 2010, but it uses the Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler. It also configures project properties to appropriate default values—for example, the specification of a compatible linker for down-level targeting. **Only apps that are created by using the vs110_xp toolset support Windows XP and Windows Server 2003**, but those apps can also supportWindows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2012.